# Artisan returning localhost as url

Tags: routes, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm using Laravel 5.2.43 to build an application. My config/app.php reads as follows:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://domain.dev'),
```

and in the .env file

```
APP_URL=domain.dev
```

my schedule send an email with a link back to the website. But this url is returned as **http://localhost** instead of **http://domain.dev**. Can someone help?

Comment: I tried changing APP_ENV in .env file and config/app.php to local/staging/production, but resulted the same.

Comment: Can you post the email blade file?

Comment: How do you generate the link?

Comment: I use route('route-to-controller') in the controller, which renders the view. Calling via http gives me the correct output. When I run it on schedule I get http://localhost

Comment: Having the same issue - and as in this case it only happens for routes that are generated inside a scheduled event / command

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to had http:// to your APP_URL
so in your case the app URL in the config file should be http://domain.dev